# Rendering issue on the first tutorial found at android.com

Tags: java, android, layout, resources, render

This question appears very often on this forum and yet I haven't been able to find a proper answer. I have followed the first android tutorial at developer.android.com
I have built a layout, taking the steps presented in the tutorial. This is the .xml file

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="horizontal" >
<EditText android:id="@+id/edit_message"
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:hint="@string/edit_message" />
<Button
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:text="@string/button_send"
android:onClick="sendMessage"
/>
</LinearLayout>
```

Everything has been saved in the Strings.xml file as shown below:

```
<string name="app_name">MyFirstApp</string>
<string name="edit_message">Enter a message</string>
<string name="button_send">Send</string>
<string name="action_settings">Settings</string>
<string name="title_activity_main">MainActivity</string>
<string name="title_activity_display_message">My Message</string>
```

And yet I am getting for both @string variables rendering error.
**Rendering Problems Couldn't resolve resource @string/edit_message (2 similar errors not shown)**

If I am changing **@string/edit_message** and **@string/button_send** with "**Something else**" it works.
*Note: I am using an android device for running the app, not a simulator.*

Thanks a lot for your answers!

Comment: If you compare yours to some arbitrary example like https://github.com/greenaddress/GreenBits/blob/master/app/src/main/res/values/strings.xml - is there anything different in the structure of your strings.xml file? The `<?xml ..` and `<resources` parts are present and your file is in `res/values/` as well? Is there any `<string` in your xml that is used successfully?

Comment: no. the files are the same. in the end it did work out after deleting and writing back a letter of the name in the resources file :o. Thanks anyway!